# vuejs, leaflet, tile and openseamap - openstreetmap

Tags: dictionary, vue.js, leaflet, tile, openseamap

I'm implementing a frontend application using vuejs, I'm relatively new in that and I need to make a single page to show a sea map and markers on it. I'm using OpenStreetMap at this time and it works with vue2-leaflet, going around on the web I found OpenSeaMap which is more suitable for my purpose, but as I saw on this page "https://wiki.openseamap.org/wiki/OpenSeaMap-dev:Server"
only markers are available. The best for me could be using base map an markers from openseamap, but at this time I'm resigning myself to use only openseamap markers. Now my question: can I put an openseamap overlay on openstreetmap base map? If so, in which way?